# ¿Obtener valores de un modelo controlado por otro modelo?

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero obtener los datos de un modelo llamado **Interruptors**, pero dependiendo de los **interruptor_id** agregados en otro modelo que se llama **Evento_Interruptors**. Me explico, deseo capturar en un array todos los interruptores que no esten en el modelo **Evento_Interruptors** y a su vez sean de un **evento_id** específico. Existe alguna clausula de **Eloquent** que haga esto.

Modelo **Evento_Interruptors**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EventoAjusteDaf extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'hora_apertura',
        'hora_cierre',
        'evento_id',
        'interruptor_id',
    ];

    public function interruptor() {
        return $this->belongsTo( Interruptor::class, 'interruptor_id', 'id' );
    }


    public function evento() {
        return $this->belongsTo( Evento::class, 'evento_id', ' id' );
    }
}
```

**Modelo Eventos**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Evento extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'fecha',
        'causa_disparo',
        'act_incorrecta',

    ];

    public function EventoAjusteDaf() {
        return $this->hasMany( EventoAjusteDaf::class, 'evento_id' );
    }

}
```

**Modelo Interruptors**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Interruptor extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [ 'name' ];

}
```

Comment: Es más fácil para entender si agregas el código de los modelos y nos muestras una idea de lo que quieres obtener.

Comment: La idea es, el modelo **Evento_Interruptors** alamacena dentro interruptores  y eventos, entonces necesito hacer un findAll al modelo **Interruptors** pero sin los q esten registrados en **Evento_Interruptors**.

Comment: el de los modelos?

Comment: ¿Es una relación muchos a muchos entre Evento e Interruptor?

Comment: Si, lo que estoy controlando la tabla Envento_Interruptors, y los el formulario hago depende de ese arreglo que quiero hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Creo que podrías definir mejor las relaciones, siguiendo las convenciones de Laravel para relaciones muchos a muchos, utilizando `belongsToMany`.
2. Deberías tener una relación definida en el Modelo Interruptor, sea con la tabla pivot o con Evento, algo como lo que tienes en este último:

   ```
   public function EventoAjusteDaf() {
       return $this->hasMany( EventoAjusteDaf::class, 'interruptor_id' );
   }
   ```
3. Para encontrar los interruptores que no tienen un evento asociado, utiliza el método `doesntHave()`, que permite traer los modelos que no tienen dicha relación:

   ```
   $interruptors = Interruptor::doesntHave('EventoAjusteDaf')->get();
   ```

   Puedes revisar su documentación en el siguiente enlace: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

---

Hago esta edición para solucionar lo que el OP plantea en los comentarios abajo:

```
$interruptors = Interruptor::doesntHave('EventoAjusteDaf', function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->whereEventoId($id);
})->get();
```

Comment: Shaz, esta consulta     $interruptors = Interruptor::doesntHave('EventoAjusteDaf')->get();     necesito q funcione pero cuando el **evento_id** del modelo **EventoAjusteDaf** sea uno determindo, como haria la clausula Where.

Comment: Shaz, logre hacerlo con esto  `$interruptors = Interruptor::whereDoesntHave( 'EventoAjusteDaf', function ( $query ) {
    $query->where( 'evento_id', '=', 24 );
   } )->get();` pero en este caso le paso un valor fijo, necesito poder pasrle un valor dinamico al **evento_id**

Comment: Y ese valor dinamico proviene de donde?, porque se lo puedes asignar a una variable y en la consulta llamas a la variable que contienes ese valor "dinamico"

Comment: @gmrYaeL no es más que el id, viene de la base de datos...

Comment: Si es el id que biene de la BD por parametro a la funcion del controlador

Comment: Shaz gracias....lo solucione con lo que pones arriba...lo deje asi  `$interruptors = Interruptor::whereDoesntHave( 'EventoAjusteDaf', function ( $query ) use ($event) {
    $query->whereEventoId( $event->id );
   } )->get();`   funciona de maravilla.